# Solving $(y'' - y)(e^x + e^{-x})=1$ using variation of parameters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can we solve $$(y'' - y)(e^x + e^{-x})=1$$ using variation of parameters?

Comment: First of all, you should write down the integrals you need to compute when you apply the method of variation of constants. Can you do this?

Answer (score 5):

We can write the DEQ as:

$$\tag 1 y'' - y = \dfrac{e^x}{e^{2x} + 1}$$

The homogeneous solution is determined by:

$$m^2 -1 = 0 \rightarrow m_{1,2} = \pm 1$$

This gives us:

$$y_h = c_1 e^{-x} + c_2e^x$$

From $y_h$, we have: $y_1 = e^{-x}, y_2 = e^x$

The Wronskian is:

$$W(e^{-x}, e^x) = 2$$

Compute $z_1$

$$z_1 = -\int \dfrac{y_2 r}{W}~ dx = -\int \dfrac{e^x e^x r}{2 (e^{2x} +1)}~dx = - \dfrac{1}{4} \ln (e^{2x}+1)$$

Compute $z_2$

$$z_2 = \int \dfrac{y_1 r}{W}~dx = \int \dfrac{1}{2 (e^{2x} +1)}~dx = \dfrac{x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{4} \ln (e^{2x}+1)$$

So:

$$y_p = z_1 y_1 + z_2 y_2 = \dfrac{1}{4}e^{-x}(2e^{2x} x - \ln(e^{2x}+1) - e^{2x} \ln(e^{2x}+1))$$

Finally

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = c_1e^{-x} + c_2 e^x + \dfrac{1}{4}e^{-x}(2e^{2x} x - \ln(e^{2x}+1) - e^{2x} \ln(e^{2x}+1))$$

Comment: Just a comment - when you are integrating for $z_1$ and $z_2$ I would leave in the constants of integration. This is because within variation of parameters we assume that the general solution will be in the form of : $y= z_1y_1 + z_2y_2$. The final answer does not differ because when you multiply, the general solution is still in the form of $y = y_h + y_p$.

Comment: It is actually a bad habit, so I would not have to recall which to treat as constants and move outside the integration.

Comment: Nice write up! +1